# Weak form of Brocard's conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

I ask this out of curiosity, motivated by a question asked by one of my students.

The [Brocard's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_conjecture) claims that there exist at least four prime numbers between $p_{i}^2$ and $p_{i+1}^2$, where $p_i$ denotes the $i^{\rm th}$ prime number ($i>1$).

> **Q.** Is it known whether there exists *at least one* prime number between 
>   $p_i^2$ and $p_{i+1}^2$?

Comment: I don't know if a positive answer to your question is already known, but it's implied by Legendre's conjecture: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture. *Edit.* I've just noted that this is also mentioned in the link to Brocard's conjecture in the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. However, it seems to me (but I'm not an expert) that Legendre's conjecture is much stronger than what I'm asking.

Comment: Legendre's conjecture implies at least two primes, check comments in OEIS:  https://oeis.org/A050216

Comment: It is not known.  A stronger conjecture which arises from playing with Eratosthenes' sieve is that there is a pair q, q+2 of twin primes between squares of consecutive primes.  (The extension to consecutive squares fails, cf. (81,100).). If the result were known, I think it would be an advance over the current record for upper bounds between prime gaps (Baker,Harman,Pintz). Gerhard "Is Minding The Prime Gaps" Paseman, 2017.06.09.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that this is not known. If $p_{i+1}-p_i$ is bounded (which we know happens infinitely often), then $p_{i+1}^2-p_i^2\ll p_{i+1}\sim p_i$, so we are looking for primes in intervals essentially as short as in Legendre's conjecture. Of course, these intervals start at specific prime squares, but I don't see how this would make the problem any easier, i.e., how a very small prime gap at $p_i$ would help us finding another prime in a reasonably short interval starting at $p_i^2$. Just my two cents.

Answer (score -7):

Not quite sure of what follows, but let's give it a try.

Suppose  $ n $ runs through a set of integers such that  $ (g_n) $  is not bounded.
Let  $ g_{n} : =p_{n+1}-p_{n} $, $ a_{i}: =\inf\{h\geq 0, g_{n}=O((\log_{i}(p_n))^h)\} $ where  $\log_{i}(n) $ is the  $ i $ -th iterate of the logarithm of  $ n $ and  $ j  : =\inf\{i\geq 0, a_{i}>0\} $ . Assume  $ j  $  is positive.

$ p^{2}_{n+1}-p^{2}_{n}=g_{n}(p_{n+1}+p_{n})>2g_{n}.p_{n}\gg 2p_{n}(\log_{j}p_n)^{a_{j}}\gg(\log_{j}(p^{2}_{n}))^{a_{j}+\varepsilon}$.

Hence  $ p^{2}_{n+1}-p^{2}_{n} $ is greater than the difference between the smallest prime greater than  $ p^{2}_{n} $ and  $ p^{2}_{n} $ , so there is a prime between  $p^{2}_{n} $ and  $ p^{2}_{n+1} $ .

Comment: $a_2$ is known to be infinite and to the best of our knowledge $a_1$ could be $0$.